# Generate images for performance testing

Tags: magento2, product-images, cli, testing, documentation

Looking at the official Magento 2 dev docs on the subject of [generating data for performance testing](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html), the [example image](http://devdocs.magento.com/common/images/config_generate-data.png) suggests that product images are generated in the process.

I ran the exact command (`magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures /var/www/html/magento2/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml`), but no product images are to be found in the backend. The rest seems to be working, though.

1. Did I forget something in the process, or is this feature not implemented (yet)?
2. Is there another way to generate product images like displayed in the dev docs (using CLI)?

Answer (score 1):

Check read permission in setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/ directory of Magento. For large volumes of data, you can use

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures \
  /var/www/html/magento/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/large.xml
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question about images at all.

Comment: @taukil thanks for the reply, but this answer does not solve my initial question about the images not being generated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the question is still valid, but the way I know to import products and from CLI is by running this command
 `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` 
this Deploys static view files, which includes images.
Then you can run your performance command and run your tests.